# How to create a polygon x meters around a path?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have two points in form of (lat, long) which is actually representing the path on map. Now I would like to create a polygon x meters around that path I have searched alot but does not find something concrete in javascript. I know how to create a polygon x meters around a point from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151645/draw-)   but as I am not a that good in mathematics so I don't know how to change it according to my requirements. Can someone please help me on this?

[image]polygon-x-meters-around-a-point

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to draw a _Polyline_ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Comment: Not polyline that I already have I want to draw a polygon I have attached a sample image

Comment: I need this to be in javascript using some algorithm not google map